# deploying Spring application on Heroku

Tags: spring, git, heroku, deployment, gradle

I'm developing Spring web services using MongoDB and I'm building it with gradle. I would like to deploy it on Heroku. I'm doing push according to documentation and I changed buildpack on gradle, according to this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

On the beginning, I'm doing `git init`, then I'm adding everything using `git add .` and commiting it using `git commit -m "message"`. After that standard procedure I'm pushing everything to heroku using `git push heroku master`.

After that, dependencies are downloaded and after that I'm getting error:

```
1 error
:compileJava FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

...

BUILD FAILED
```

And here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'appname'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb")

    compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'installApp'])
```

Anyone has solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your application is simply failing to compile. This could be for any number of reasons. Try simply running your Gradle build locally with `gradlew compileJava`. You should get a more useful message.

Comment: App is running correctly locally using `gradle compileJava`. `gradlew` is not working on my cmd.

Comment: Might try removing maven local from your list of repositories. That could cause issues when building remotely.

Comment: No, I'm still having same error even I removed mavenLocal().

Comment: Can you try removing the `apply plugin: 'application'` and `mavenLocal()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to show you a best set of files and you can compare where we differ. One of the biggest things to mention is that you are not even compiling which may have nothing to do with compilation on Heroku's end.

Link to the Github project if anyone needs it! https://github.com/arose13/Heroku-Spring-Gradle_Example

The Procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar app.jar
```

An Example Gradle file

```
group 'com.springtest.api'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

mainClassName = "hello.Application"

jar {
    baseName = 'spring-test-api'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

    // Spring Framework
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}

task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)

clean << {
    project.file('app.jar').delete()
}
```